# When can you AC couple LVDS?

Tags: lvds

According to Wikipedia [Wikipedia-LVDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling#:%7E:text=Low%2Dvoltage%20differential%20signaling%2C%20or,inexpensive%20twisted%2Dpair%20copper%20cables.), 350mV signal (700mV differential) is developed when a 3.5mA current flows through 100 ohm differential resistor. and according to this app note from Analog Devices [Analog Devices AN-586](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/5957542118600205599850975382134073431740717454123180480718an586.pdf), "LVDS outputs are current output stages requiring a 100 ohm terminating resistor at the receiver"

Section 9.3.2, page 26, of LMK00306's datasheet [LMK00306 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmk00306.pdf?ts=1644334560673&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMK00306) also mentions a need for having DC coupled termination at a driver side if AC coupled.

However, I see many app notes like this one, [TI app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa840/slaa840.pdf?ts=1644298667476&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) (figures 3-5), using direct connection between a driver and AC coupling caps without a terminating resistor.
If there's no DC coupled resistor at the output of LVDS driver side like a figure below, where will 3.5mA current go and what will be an amplitude of LVDS signal?

When can you AC couple like figure 3, and when do you need a DC coupled 100 ohm resistor at a driver output?

[image: LVDS_AC_coupled]

Comment: 9.3.2 tells you why.

Comment: @Andyaka No, that's not the question I asked. I asked how can figure 3 and any other AC coupled LVDS connection with a driver having no DC coupled termination work if 9.3.2 says a driver needs DC coupled termination

Comment: Because 9.3.2 applies to the chip it is describing. It never claims to be a generic description of all LVDS chips does it?

Comment: @andyaka, I don't think you understand the question. Operating principle of LVDS is a driver supplies constant 3.5mA current to an 100ohm load to create 350mV amplitude signal. My question was NOT asking why 9.3.2 works. But rather how figure 3 works. If you ac couple and a driver doesn't have this DC path to create a known amplitude, then how do you know amplitude of the signal

Comment: Do you know how transmission lines work? Do you know how high frequencies will pass that current through any reasonably sized capacitor and use the 100 ohm load at the far end as a termination.

Comment: @andyaka I know the concept but definitely I'm no expert. You sound you are expert on that area. Then how about providing some explanation rather than answering a question with a question? Also you might be able to answer why do some LVDS drivers need DC coupled termination and some don't if an LVDS has a standard unlike CML and LVPECL. But then again, if you want to answer a question with a question then you don't have to waste your time.

Comment: sp2821 - I'll tell you what I don't understand (and this is a common problem with some questions); I don't understand the difficulty you are having understanding this. I know there is something you don't understand but, for the life of me I can't fathom that out. So, not wishing to start an essay on the subject that might end several pages later, I'm disinclined to make an answer that might somewhere, in a little corner reveal something to you that explains what it is you don't understand. So, really, the ball is in your court to dig deeper and state what it is precisely that confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver DC bias resistors, 130 in parallel with 82 ohm, form a 50 ohm termination single-ended termination. The differential impedance will be 100 ohms. The resistors need to be as close to the receiver pins as possible.

Why you might AC couple depends if you have significant common mode voltage differences between the transmitter and receiver sides that is outside the range of the receiver inputs. I normally use transformer coupling between equipment using different power sources for LVDS signals.

One thing to heed in the article is making sure your data is DC balanced using some sort of encoding scheme when AC coupling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still don't understand how figure 3 above would work if the driver doesn't see DC path to 100 ohm termination resistor. My understanding of an LVDS driver is, it supplies a constant 3.5mA current to a load which is typically 100ohm differential and thus 350mV SE signal. If there's no DC path for the current as in the figure 3, then what will be the amplitude?

Comment: @sp2821 At high frequencies, there is no DC.

Comment: The transmitted data must be encoded in a way that it has no DC, or too low frequencies, so that the data can pass through the capacitors, without too long "baseline wander"